# Como fazer para Navigate executar uma vez ou para de executar

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Em minha pagina Login tenho duas condições, se o usuário estiver deslogado irá renderizar a parte do formulário, mas se o usuário estiver logado executará `<Navigate to="home">`.
Porém não consigo mais executar outros navigates ou Links, pois esse Navigate está impedindo de renderizar outra pagina

```
import { Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { useState, useEffect, Component, useContext, createContext } from "react"
import { loginAuthContext, AuthUserLogin } from "../../Contexts/AuthLogin.jsx"
import { Alert } from "@mui/material"

export function Tela_login() {

   const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState()
   const [userPass, setUserPass] = useState()
   const [status, setStatus] = useState(null)


   const { login, signed, errorMensage, user, setErrorMensage } = useContext(loginAuthContext)
   // console.log(errorMensage)
   useEffect(() => {
       // console.log(errorMensage)
       Verific()
       sessionStorage.removeItem('@AuthError')
   }, [errorMensage])



   async function Verific() {
       const ero = sessionStorage.getItem('@AuthError')

       if (ero) {
           console.log("entrou23")
           setStatus(<Alert severity="error" onClose={() => {
               setStatus(null)
               setErrorMensage(null)
           }}>Verifique suas credênciais! E-mail ou Senha Inválidos</Alert>)

       }

   }


   async function loginServer() {


       await login(userEmail, userPass)
       Verific()

   }


   if (signed == false || sessionStorage.getItem("@AuthFirebase:user") == "null") {

       return (
           <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center container--mn" id="princ">
               <div className="py-3">
                   {status}

               </div>
               <h1 >Bem Vindo ao Gnet</h1>
               <form className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                   <div className="col-md-4 ">
                       <div className="form-group">
                           <label htmlFor="Nome">Email</label>
                           <input onChange={e => setUserEmail(e.target.value)} id="addEmail" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Email..." />
                       </div>

                       <div className="form-group">
                           <label htmlFor="Senha">Senha</label>
                           <input onChange={e => setUserPass(e.target.value)} id="addPassword" type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Senha..." />
                       </div>

                       <button onClick={() => loginServer()} type="button" id="addButton" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">Entrar</button>
                       <div className="text-center my-2">OU</div>
                       <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark button--google "><i className="bi bi-google pe-2"></i>Entrar com o Google</button>

                       <div className="text-center pt-4 ">
                           <span>Não possui cadastro? <Link to="tela-cadastro/">Clique Aqui</Link></span>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </form>
           </div>
       )
   } else {

       return <Navigate to="/home" />
   }


}
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá,

Este problema está acontecendo, pois o código `return <Navigate to="/home" />` está interrompendo a utilização dos demais componentes.

O que você pode realizar para resolver este caso, seria o seguinte (dentro do else):

`return <HomePage />`

E em outra função fazer a lógica do HomePage com o Navigate para a home:

`function HomePage() { return } // Lógica e conteúdo da página Home`

Comment: No caso você diz para chamar o componente home e executa-lo no return? Ou criar um Navigate dentro da função?